# How Can I Create Session Id For The User And Auto Generate Randomly User Id

Tags: android, mysql

Good day, I just would like to asked if,

---

**how can I generate session id for the user and also a unique random id, not the id which is auto increment?**

---

I'm making a project that is so much related with social networking site. Here's my sample table for the user. I created a table for user (user_sessions).

[image: User Info]

Comment: Try `java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: Or mysql's uuid() function.